# Eta-conversion changes semantics in a strict language

Tags: haskell, lambda, ocaml, lazy-evaluation, ml

Take this OCaml code:

```ml
let silly (g : (int -> int) -> int) (f : int -> int -> int) =
        g (f (print_endline "evaluated"; 0))

silly (fun _ -> 0) (fun x -> fun y -> x + y)
```

It prints `evaluated` and returns `0`. But if I eta-expand `f` to get `g (fun x -> f (print_endline "evaluated"; 0) x)`, `evaluated` is no longer printed.

Same holds for this SML code:

```ml
fun silly (g : (int -> int) -> int, f : int -> int -> int) : int =
        g (f (print "evaluated" ; 0));

silly ((fn _ => 0), fn x => fn y => x + y);
```

On the other hand, this Haskell code doesn't print `evaluated` even with the strict pragma:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE Strict #-}

import Debug.Trace

silly :: ((Int -> Int) -> Int) -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int
silly g f = g (f (trace "evaluated" 0))

main = print $ silly (const 0) (+)
```

(I can make it, though, by using `seq`, which makes perfect sense for me)

While I understand that OCaml and SML do the right thing theoretically, are there any practical reason to prefer this behaviour to the "lazier" one? Eta-contraction is a common refactoring tool and I'm totally scared of using it in a strict language. I feel like I should paranoically eta-expand everything, just because otherwise arguments to partially applied functions can be evaluated when they're not supposed to. When is the "strict" behaviour useful?

Why and how does Haskell behave differently under the `Strict` pragma? Are there any references I can familiarize myself with to better understand the design space and pros and cons of the existing approaches?

Comment: Ocaml and SML kind of have no choice in this matter. It's an inevitable consequence of applicative order of evaluation. In Haskell, the Strict pragma only applies to bindings and data types, expressions are still lazy.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, "It's an inevitable consequence of applicative order of evaluation" -- my questions are exactly about what happens if you rebel and break the order in this particular regard. Automatic eta-expansion to the proletariat!
"In Haskell, the Strict pragma only applies to bindings and data types" -- thanks, I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address the technical part of your question, eta-conversion also changes the meaning of expressions in lazy languages, you just need to consider the eta-rule of a different type constructor, e.g., + instead of ->.

This is the eta-rule for binary sums:

```
(case e of Lft y -> f (Lft y) | Rgt y -> f (Rgt y))  =  f e    (eta-+)
```

This equation holds under eager evaluation, because `e` will always be reduced on both sides. Under lazy evaluation, however, the r.h.s. only reduces `e` if `f` also forces it. That might make the l.h.s. diverge where the r.h.s. would not. So the equation does not hold in a lazy language.

To make it concrete in Haskell:

```
f x = 0
lhs = case undefined of Left y -> f (Left y); Right y -> f (Right y)
rhs = f undefined
```

Here, trying to print `lhs` will diverge, whereas `rhs` yields `0`.

There is more that could be said about this, but the essence is that the equational theories of both evaluation regimes are sort of dual.

The underlying problem is that under a lazy regime, every type is inhabited by `_|_` (non-termination), whereas under eager it is not. That has severe semantic consequences. In particular, there are no inductive types in Haskell, and you cannot prove termination of a structural recursive function, e.g., a list traversal.

There is a line of research in type theory distinguishing data types (strict) from codata types (non-strict) and providing both in a dual manner, thus giving the best of both worlds.

*Edit:* As for the question why a compiler should not eta-expand functions: that would utterly break every language. In a strict language with effects that's most obvious, because the ability to *stage* effects via multiple function abstractions is a feature. The simplest example perhaps is this:

```
let make_counter () =
  let x = ref 0 in
  fun () -> x := !x + 1; !x

let tick = make_counter ()
let n1 = tick ()
let n2 = tick ()
let n3 = tick ()
```

But effects are not the only reason. Eta-expansion can also drastically change the performance of a program! In the same way you sometimes want to stage effects you sometimes also want to stage *work*:

```
match :: String -> String -> Bool
match regex = \s -> run fsm s
  where fsm = ...expensive transformation of regex...

matchFloat = match "[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?((e|E)(+|-)?[0-9]+)?"
```

Note that I used Haskell here, because this example shows that implicit eta-expansion is not desirable in either eager or lazy languages!

Comment: While this is interesting, it does not touch my practical concerns. What would happen if we automatically eta-expand all functions in a strict language? Would that break something? Would that made something deeply counter-intuitive? I just do not understand why I should do this manually when a language can do this for me and save me some headache.

Comment: Implicit eta-expansion would definitely be a terrible idea, in both eager and lazy languages. See my edit.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your examples. I do not see the difference between `\s -> run fsm s` and `run fsm` in your Haskell example and besides even if you bind that `s` directly in `match`, that wouldn't change anything due to `full-laziness`. I see what your ML snippet does, but do not understand how eta-conversion can affect that. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Actually, I think I understand now. With effects it's at the very least not clear whether to expand before a `let` or after. Both approaches have their advantages, but both are rather arbitrary and silently affect semantics of an expression in a non-trivial way. Yeah, perfect example, thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you think is arbitrary about interpreting a program exactly as it is written. Inserting unrequested eta expansions would indeed be very arbitrary.

Comment: I meant that whether you insert a lambda before or after `let`, it is arbitrary in any case.

Comment: I don't understand this statement. No lambda is inserted. When "partially" applying a curried function you are simply calling a function that returns a value that also happens to be a function. There is nothing special about returning a function.

Comment: "No lambda is inserted." -- yes. Sorry I must be really unclear. I mean that if you do what I proposed, i.e. insert a lambda, you're forced to do an arbitrary choice which is silly.

Comment: Ah, okay, now I get what you were saying. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your final question (why does Haskell do this), the reason "Strict Haskell" behaves differently from a truly strict language is that the `Strict` extension doesn't really change the evaluation model from lazy to strict.  It just makes a subset of bindings into "strict" bindings by default, and only in the **limited Haskell sense** of forcing evaluation to weak head normal form.  Also, it only affects bindings made in the module with the extension turned on; it doesn't retroactively affect bindings made elsewhere.  (Moreover, as described below, the strictness doesn't take effect in partial function application.  The function needs to be fully applied before any arguments are forced.)

In your particular Haskell example, I believe the only effect of the `Strict` extension is as if you had explicitly written the following bang patterns in the definition of `silly`:

```
silly !g !f = g (f (trace "evaluated" 0))
```

It has no other effect.  In particular, it doesn't make `const` or `(+)` strict in their arguments, nor does it generally change the semantics of function applications to make them eager.

So, when the term `silly (const 0) (+)` is forced by `print`, the only effect is to evaluate its arguments to WHNF as part of the function application of `silly`.  The effect is similar to writing (in non-`Strict` Haskell):

```
let { g = const 0; f = (+) } in g `seq` f `seq` silly g f
```

Obviously, forcing `g` and `f` to their WHNFs (which are lambdas) isn't going to have any side effect, and when `silly` is applied, `const 0` is still lazy in its remaining argument, so the resulting term is something like:

```
(\x -> 0) ((\x y -> <defn of plus>) (trace "evaluated" 0))
```

(which should be interpreted without the `Strict` extension -- these are all lazy bindings here), and there's nothing here that will force the side effect.

As noted above, there's another subtle issue that this example glosses over.  Even if you had made everything in sight strict:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Strict #-}

import Debug.Trace

myConst :: a -> b -> a
myConst x y = x

myPlus :: Int -> Int -> Int
myPlus x y = x + y

silly :: ((Int -> Int) -> Int) -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int
silly g f = g (f (trace "evaluated" 0))

main = print $ silly (myConst 0) myPlus
```

this still wouldn't have printed "evaluated".  This is because, in the evaluation of `silly` when the strict version of `myConst` forces its second argument, that argument is a partial application of the strict version of `myPlus`, and `myPlus` won't force any of its arguments until it's been fully applied.

This also means that if you change the definition of `myPlus` to:

```
myPlus x = \y -> x + y   -- now it will print "evaluated"
```

then you'll be able to largely reproduce the ML behavior.  Because `myPlus` is now fully applied, it will force its argument, and this will print "evaluated".  You can suppress it again eta-expanding `f` in the definition of `silly`:

```
silly g f = g (\x -> f (trace "evaluated" 0) x)  -- now it won't
```

because now when `myConst` forces its second argument, that argument is already in WHNF (because it's a lambda), and we never get to the application of `f`, full or not.

In the end, I guess I wouldn't take "Haskell plus the `Strict` extension and unsafe side effects like `trace`" too seriously as a good point in the design space.  Its semantics may be (barely) coherent, but they sure are weird.  I think the only serious use case is when you have some code whose semantics "obviously" don't depend on lazy versus strict evaluation but where performance would be improved by a lot of forcing.  Then, you can just turn on `Strict` for a performance boost without having to think too hard.

Comment: Yeah, I got from the Fyodor Soikin's comment that I just didn't understand how `Strict` really works in Haskell. The "subtle issue" point is helpful, thanks.